# MongoDB Atlas Connection prob

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

Has any of your experienced and solved this issue on MongoDB where in it shows this error when connecting to the DB through the Mongo shell

`DNSHostNotFound: Failed to look up service "":No records found for given DNS query. try 'mongo --help' for more information`

I have the mongo added into the path, unfortunately this is blocking me from continuing to use MongoDB Atlas.

Answer (score 1):

From the error it seems that the srv connection string is not being resolved.

1. Could you try to connect using the standard connection string.